# Unable to connect to MySQL through port 3306

Tags: mysql, firewall, port

I read the answers about 3306 from a question posted in 2009. I have the same problem, but the answers I read didn't help. Port 3306 is open, even if I stop the [windows-firewall](/questions/tagged/windows-firewall), MySQL still can't access it. MySQL is running. I've run `netstat firewall xxxxxx` and get these results:

```
3306   TCP       Enable   MySQL Server
```

and this from `netstat -a -n`:

```
TCP    [::]:3306              [::]:0                 LISTENING       0
```

(I don't understand the [::])

I do have AVG Internet Security running but not the Firewall component. How can I find out what is blocking MySQL from accessing this port? And it's not just this specific port, but any port. I've asked on the MySQL forum, but no one is replying.

Comment: What does `ipconfig /all` shows?

Comment: Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:



        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface

        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF

        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No

        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : fe80::ffff:ffff:fffxxx

        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 

        NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Answer (score 4):

Here is a config snippet that should be informative:

```
[mysqld]

# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=3306

# default IPv6，so change to ipv4 
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: A bit more explanation would help

Answer (score 2):

Try bind-address=0.0.0.0 in my.ini
Works on my PC.

Comment: I tried it but the config app just hung.

Comment: Edit the my.ini file in Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server X.Y and restart the MySQL Server. Add the bind-address to the [mysqld] section. I'm not using the config app. I'm assuming your problem is that you can't get the MySql client to connect to the MySql server?

Answer (score 1):

There is also a bind-address setting in my.cnf which, if it is set to 127.0.0.1 (which is the default I believe), will prevent remote clients from connecting.

Comment: I am on Windows XP. I don't see any my.cnf. I have a my.ini but there is no bind-address setting there.

Comment: my.ini is equivalent to my.cnf. I do not use Windows MySQL but it can't do any harm putting bind-address = a.b.c.d in it & restarting mysql, if the defaults are the same as Linux it might do the trick. If it doesn't then take it out, restart mysql again and try something else.

Comment: I should have said that a.b.c.d should be the IP address of your host.

Comment: bind-address=127.0.0.1 didn't help.

Comment: I meant put bind-address=what the IP address of your host is, absolutely not 127.0.0.1 that will definitely stop it working!

Comment: I put in the local network access of my computer, a 192.168 number and that didn't work.

Comment: Any other ideas? Anyone able to offer a solution or even a course of action?

Comment: In other words no one has a clue.

Comment: Yes, 127.0.0.1 is default on Debian, for example - so it'll only respond to requests addressed to 127.0.0.1, which means it'll only work from the same machine (you can't even connect from the host computer if you're running MySQL on a virtual machine).

Answer (score 0):

it means it is listening on ipv6 (thats why you can't connect to it with ipv4)

Comment: But, I didn't specify IPv4. There is no place to specify that. How do I change it back?

Comment: For instance, under my Local Area Network, Microsoft TCP/IP Version 6 is checked. BUT, if I uncheck it won't I be cut off from IvP6 later on? Is there a way to restrict a port to IvP4?

Comment: You to specify IPv4 address in order to connect to the server.

Comment: HOW do i do this?

Comment: Can someone please tell me how to specify a port refers to IPv4 and not IPv6?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check **skip-networking** part on your `my.cnf`?
It shoud be

```
 #skip-networking
```

Answer (score -2):

jyoti Gurjar@:

go to Control Panel-->Network and internet Connection-->Change Firewall Setting--> Exceptions--> Add prt--> then type ,port name=MySql and port no.=3306. -->ok

:):):)

Comment: He has already mentioned that disabling the firewall does not work.